# how get event click of the any images on canvas apiRest

Tags: canvas

I have a canvas where by means of a rest service I get a list of images with their path, x - y coordinate, also their height and width. I am drawing these images on the canvas.
My idea is to know how to click on it and obtain an ID or something that allows me to consult your individual information by means of another call to the rest api.

I would like to know what is the concept to carry out this task to adjust it to my code.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the visual content of a canvas element is not accessible by the dom you cannot add event listeners on specific graphical elements within a canvas.

Nevertheless you can add a click event listener to the canvas element itself and determine programmatically which image has been clicked within the canvas. This can be achieved by comparing the current position of the cursor with the coordinates and size of each image in your list each time a click event occurs.

Let's say you have a list of all images within the canvas like this:

```js
const images = [{
   url: './imageA.png'
   x: 10,
   y: 25,
   height: 50,
   width: 50,
   onClick: (evt) => {
      // imageA.png got clicked
   }
}, {
   url: './imageB.png'
   x: 80,
   y: 50,
   height: 50,
   width: 50,
   onClick: (evt) => {
      // imageB.png got clicked
   }
}];
```

Now, you can listen for a click event within the canvas and manually check if a specific image got clicked:

```js
// get relative cursor position within canvas
const getRelativeCursorPosition = ({clientX, clientY}) => {
  const canvasBcr = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = clientX - canvasBcr.x;
  const y = clientY - canvasBcr.y;
  
  return {x, y}
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
   const cursor = getRelativeCursorPosition(evt);

   for (img of images) {
      // check if relative cursor position is within img dimensions
      if (img.x < cursor.x &&
      img.x + img.width > cursor.x &&
      img.y < cursor.y &&
      img.y + img.height > cursor.y) {
         img.onClick(evt);
    }
  }
});
```

See a [working demo](https://codepen.io/felixgro/pen/GRvBzLY) of this approach on codepen.

Answer (score 0):

just use a click event and check the x and y against all the images.
Say you have an array of images, just loop through check if click x/y is more than image x/y and less than image x/y + width/height.